# Comparison question string vs int

Tags: powershell-2.0

Can someone explain to me why these comparisons work they way the do. I had a bug in one of my scripts that took me a little bit to work through. I was using read-host and typing a number. It was storing it as a string.

```
Write-Host "(`'2`' -gt 9 ) = " ('2' -gt 9 )
Write-Host "(2 -gt 9 ) = " (2 -gt 9 )
Write-Host "(`'2`' -gt 10 ) = " ('2' -gt 10 )
```

If you are comparing a string to an Int does it use the Ascii value? If so why does the first one show $false, it should be $true.

Then how is it when you change the int to 10 it becomes $true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On comparison a right value is converted to the type of a left value. Thus, `'2' -gt 9` becomes `'2' -gt '9'`, that is False, and `'2' -gt 10` becomes `'2' -gt '10'`, that is True.

Comment: Roman can you point me to a link on how the strings compare with -gt, -lt and so forth. I understand the conversion process now but still confused on why '2' is greater then '10'.

Thanks

Comment: I will try to rephrase. I think you are confused by *numbers* in strings but they are just characters. Forget about *numbers*, think *characters*. To make it easier replace 0->a, 1->b, 2->c and you will get "c" and "ba" analogues for "2" and "10". Now, "c" -gt "b" (alphabetically) just like "2" -gt "1". And any string starting with "c" is -gt any string starting with "b", e.g. "c" -gt "ba". The same is true for any string "2...." and "1....", for example "2" -gt "10".

Comment: Thank you, I think I was confused on how strings compare when you don't have the same number of characters on each side. It only compares the amount of characters that are on the left.